Weird \widehat behaviour caused by packages amsmath, amssymb and fouriernc
I want to type
The code is
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}
    \[f \ast g(x) = \widehat{\widehat{f \ast g}} (-x) = \widehat{\widehat{f}\widehat{g}}(-x)\]
\end{document}

However, when loading the packages amsmath and amssymb, the last part is not displayed correctly.

It looks as if a random f \ast g appeared underneath the \widehat{\widehat{f}\widehat{g}}. The code that produces this is
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}
    \[f \ast g(x) = \widehat{\widehat{f \ast g}} (-x) = \widehat{\widehat{f}\widehat{g}}(-x)\]
\end{document}

When removing any of the packages amsmath, amssymb or fouriernc, the triple widehat is displayed correctly, but loading the three packages together causes this strange behaviour.

fourierenc and ams*  use completely different font encodings

You shouldn't be loading amssymb along with fouriernc, which already provides the symbol set.
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}

\[
  f \ast g(x)
  = \widehat{\widehat{f \ast g}} (-x)
  = \widehat{\widehat{f}\widehat{g}}(-x)
\]

\end{document}


